# Groupby and aggregation based on latest timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have input that looks like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrOM4.png)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name': ['Andy', 'Andy', 'Ramesh', 'Ramesh', 'Suresh', 'Suresh'],
                    'Class':[10,10,12,12,12,12],
                    'Section':['B','','C', 'D', '', ''],
                    'Time':[12,13,15,17,19,20]})

    Name  Class Section  Time
0    Andy     10       B    12
1    Andy     10            13
2  Ramesh     12       C    15
3  Ramesh     12       D    17
4  Suresh     12            19
5  Suresh     12            20
```

I want to convert the dataframe to following format:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOHCW.png)

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name': ['Andy','Ramesh', 'Suresh'],
                        'Class':[10,12,12],
                        'Section':['B','D',''],
                        'Time':[12,17,20]}) 
      Name  Class Section  Time
0    Andy     10       B    12
1  Ramesh     12       D    17
2  Suresh     12            20
```

So basically what I want to do is groupBy "Name, Class"  and for "Section" Column, I want latest(according to Time) non null value of Section. Like for andy, 10 latest section according to Time Value is null but I want 'B'. That is not null. and for Ramesh,12 section is D according to latest Time Value. And like for Suresh,12 Section is null for all Time, therefore Section value comes 'null' having latest Time. If possible need spark scala code for it

Comment: Why did you revert the perfectly sensible edit that was made on your question? Please refrain from using screenshots of DataFrames. Copy-pastable DataFrames (as the ones in the edit) are the best way to go. Also, how is this question related to Google BigQuery or Scala? It looks exclusively like a Pandas question. You should update your tags, I think.

Comment: Hey @UJIN, I was new to to Stack thats why I didn't know about the copy paste feature of Stack. Secondly, I want to implement this as Scala code, not Pandas, but as pandas can provide me logic for the same, I used tag under Pandas too.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#that really depends on how your null characters are
df['Section']=df['Section'].replace('',np.nan)


where=df['Section'].notnull()
not_all_null=df.groupby(['Name','Class']).Section.transform('first').isnull() | where


new_df=(df.sort_values('Time',ascending=False)
          .assign(Time=df['Time'].where(not_all_null),Section=df['Section'].where(where))
          .groupby(['Name','Class'],as_index=False)
          .first().fillna('') )
print(new_df)


     Name  Class Section  Time
0    Andy     10       B  12.0
1  Ramesh     12       D  17.0
2  Suresh     12          20.0
```

Comment: Hey ansev, problem with the output is , If for any groupby there is an entry where section is null for all records, then I want to keep the record with null value

Comment: please check now!:)

Comment: Whats where(where) in Section=df['Section'].where(where)).

Comment: I forget to specify this. I have updated the solution, keep in mind that you have to be sure that string considers null, that is, you must be sure that you have '' and not ' ' or more spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary column with the following logic in SQL:

```
IF(Section is null, null, Time)
```

sort rows by this column plus `Time` column both in descending orders, and then find the first row of each partition/group (using Window *row_number()* function with Spark or *drop_duplicates()* with Pandas)

### With Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when,row_number}

val df = Seq(
        ("Andy", "10", "B", 12)
      , ("Andy", "10", null, 13)
      , ("Ramesh", "12", "C", 15)
      , ("Ramesh", "12", "D", 17)
      , ("Suresh", "12", null, 19)
      , ("Suresh", "12", null, 20)
    ).toDF("Name", "Class", "Section", "Time")

val w1 = Window.partitionBy("Name", "Class").orderBy(desc("tmp_col"), desc("Time"))

var df_new = (df.withColumn("tmp_col", when($"Section".isNotNull, $"Time"))
    .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w1))
    .filter("rn = 1"))

df_new.show
+------+-----+-------+----+-------+---+
|  Name|Class|Section|Time|tmp_col| rn|
+------+-----+-------+----+-------+---+
|Ramesh|   12|      D|  17|     17|  1|
|  Andy|   10|      B|  12|     12|  1|
|Suresh|   12|   null|  20|   null|  1|
+------+-----+-------+----+-------+---+

df_new = df_new.drop("tmp_col", "rn")
```

### With Pandas:

use the same logic, added `df.Section.eq('')` in the IF condition to reflect the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['tmp_col'] = np.where(df.Section.eq('') | df.Section.isna(), None, df.Time)
df.sort_values(['tmp_col', 'Time'], ascending=[0,0]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Class'])

#     Name  Class Section  Time tmp_col
#3  Ramesh     12       D    17      17
#0    Andy     10       B    12      12
#5  Suresh     12            20    None
```